# jQuery: click to enlarge and move

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I come with yet another question on jQuery :
So i have this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    $("#block1").animate({width:7em,height:7em});
    $("#block2").animate({width:7em,height:7em});
    $("#block3").animate({width:7em,height:7em});
    $("#block4").animate({width:7em,height:7em});
    $("#block5").animate({width:7em,height:7em,function(){
        $(this).animate({width:20em,height:20em,top:4em,left:8em});
    });
});
});
```

that is supposed to get some "post-it" shaped boxes to 
1: get all the boxes back to their original position and size
2: pop out of their original position to go in the middle of the screen while enlarging when clicked on..
do you have any idea why this doesn't work? (i don't want a css hover, but if there is another way to do this via css, i'm ok with it!!)

Comment: Why are you binding the `click` handler to the document?

Comment: My first catch is that your method call isn't quite right. `.animate({width:7em,height:7em)};` - brackets are around the wrong way.

Comment: hehe.. ok my main objective is to bind it on whichever of the 5 blocks i'm clicking on.. not quite working out this way, right, =)

Comment: Second catch is that (I think) you need to have your `em`'s in quotes.

Comment: yeah sorry, the brackets are actually in the right way on my real code =$

Comment: You should probably just copy and paste your real code - because the one above is a bit of a mess.

Comment: make it simple : here's a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q5RwE/

Comment: this link will help you a lot http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation

Comment: hi.... i know you will do it easily ....

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Do you want the animations to be triggered by a click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    $("#block1").animate({width:"7em",height:"7em"});
    $("#block2").animate({width:"7em",height:"7em"});
    $("#block3").animate({width:"7em",height:"7em"});
    $("#block4").animate({width:"7em",height:"7em"});
    $("#block5").animate({width:"7em",height:"7em"},function(){
       $(this).animate({width:"20em",height:"20em",top:"4em",left:"8em"});
    });
  });
});
```

1) missing a closing brace in line 7  "$("#block5").animate({width:"7em",height:"7em" '}' ,function(){"

2) also u need to include jquery file

3) to animate u need to give height and width greater than element's current height and width to see the effect i.e more than 7em as in css u already have given 7em

4) also there is no Id given to elements as I found in your jsFiddle link

All above points mentioned are based on link http://jsfiddle.net/q5RwE/2/  given by you

Comment: Thanks!! sorry about the few things i was missing in my jsfiddle, your answer is perfect! ;) +1 and vote

Answer (score 1):

Change your code something like this

.animate({width:"7em",height:"7em"});